# Xamarin solution only builds with MSBuildPlatform.x86

Tags: xamarin, msbuild, cakebuild

I have the following question:

I'm using CakeBuild to build my Xamarin.Forms solution on a Windows computer (Windows 10).

Everything builds fine when I'm using the following command:

```
MSBuild("MyXamarinApp.sln", configurator =>
        configurator.SetConfiguration("Debug")
          .SetMSBuildPlatform(MSBuildPlatform.x86));
```

But if I remove "SetMSBuildPlatform(MSBuildPlatform.x86)" it uses internally "MSBuildPlatform.x64" and then I get the following error:

```
(_GetReferenceAssemblyPaths target) ->
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Xamarin\Android\Xamarin.Android.Common.targets(566,2): error MSB3644: The reference assemblies for framework "MonoAndroid,Version=v1.0" were not found. To resolve this, install the SDK or Targeting Pack for this framework version or retarget your application to a version of the framework for which you have the SDK or Targeting Pack installed. Note that assemblies will be resolved from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC) and will be used in place of reference assemblies. Therefore your assembly may not be correctly targeted for the framework you intend.
```

Can someone explain this behaviour? Can I only use the x86 version of MSBuild to build Xamarin projects?

Answer (score 0):

You need to set that platform in you Android application target. (AndroidProject -> Options).

x86 that desktop architecture. You can use it to build and test on simulator, but for a real device you will need to select at least one mobile architecture (any architecture that's not x86 or x86_64)

[image]

Comment: I don't think that this is realted to my question. I do not generate an APK file at the moment. I just do a rebuild of the whole solution including the Android project. 

"MSBuildPlatform" defines just which MSBuild.exe is used to complile the solution. If "MSBuildPlatform.x86" is used then the MSBuild.exe from "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin" is used. If "MSBuildPlatform.x64" is used then the MSBuild.exe from "C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\amd64" is used. And when the MSBuild.exe within the directory "amd64" is used, then the Android project can't be build.